# "This Card is Already in wallet" message when I'm trying to add card to Wallet & Apple Pay which was removed

Tags: wallet

I removed credit card and I'm trying to add it again in "Wallet & Apple Pay", but I get the message as in title.
At iWatch I removed and added the same card without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I removed other cards which I had already in Wallet and then one by one added them, also the problematic card.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all cards from wallet and when I wanted to re-add these got the message "card already in wallet". Online all solutions pointed me to iCloud but the portal has been changes and these solutions were no longer relevant.

The following solved the problem for me:

1. On iPhone go to Settings app and click on top section where your picture is (Apple Id, iCloud settings).
2. Select your phone in the list of devices at the bottom of this screen
3. At the bottom you will see "Wallet & Apple Pay" - from here you can click on "Remove Items"
4. Re-add your cards, no error will be displayed